# How to hide (remove) 'Owner' and 'Computer' information on RAR file?

Tags: windows, rar, winrar

I would like to share a RAR file but When I right click (Explorer) on file and go to 'Details' tab, it shows my computer name and owner name. How do I remove (hide) this information?

i use Winrar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Details tab is showing the file-system information, therefore those information is not part of the file. If you copy your RAR file to an Internet service (or an USB-Stick that is FAT formatted) those information are lost because they are not part of the file.

If you want to make sure there are no personal meta-data included in the RAR look at it in WinRAR and an hex editor and search for your personal data you don't want to include in the RARA file.

Comment: @Xavierjazz: done ;)